# Why does Informix .NET provider slow down?

Tags: .net, informix

I'm trying to insert 10,000 rows into four Informix tables (2,500 per table) using the .NET provider through one connection and inside a transaction (BEGIN WORK/COMMIT WORK).  Each table has about 20 columns, a char(20) primary key, and an index on one other char column.

The first few rows are inserted at a rate of about 500/second.  The insertions slow down until it's around 10/second at the end.

I tried breaking the task up into transactions of 1000 rows at a time, with a new connection for each transaction, but the slowdown was the same.  The connection and the command were Disposed after each block was complete.  I even tried putting a Sleep(10000ms) after each transaction.

Finally, I changed the program to insert 1,000 rows at a time, starting at a given row number.  The first time the program ran, it inserted rows 1-1,000.  The second time it ran, it inserted rows 1,001-2,000, and so on.  Each successive run of the program started 3 or 4 seconds after the end of the preceding run.

The slowdown vanished.  Rows 9,000-10,000 were inserted at roughly the same 500 rows/second rate as rows 1-1,000.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get a single transaction of 10,000 rows to insert at a more or less constant rate?

Answer (score 1):

We didn't figure out what happened with the .NET provider, but swapping in the ODBC driver eliminated the problem.